# How to reset defaultValue attribute for an input on form onSubmit event?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component

```
import * as React from 'react';

const taskAdd = (props: { handleAdd: any }) => {
    return (
        <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={props.handleAdd}>
            <table className="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name"></input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="priority" placeholder="Priority"></input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    );
}

export default taskAdd;
```

it works fine, but the issue is that when I add new task to my todolist I would also like to empty the input fields. How to do that? I tried to use `state` properties and reset them in `handleAdd` event, but it didn't have any effect.

[image]

Any idea?

Working code based on Faroot Sedat answer

```
import * as React from 'react';

const TaskAdd = (props: { handleAdd: any }) => {

    const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
    const [priority, setPriority] = React.useState("");

    const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
        // reset fields
        setName("");
        setPriority("");

        // redirect event
        props.handleAdd(e);
    };

    const handleChangeName = (e: any) => {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleChangePriority = (e: any) => {
        setPriority(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <table className="table" style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name"
                                value={name}
                                onChange={handleChangeName}></input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="priority" placeholder="Priority"
                                value={priority}
                                onChange={handleChangePriority}></input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    );
}

export default TaskAdd;
```

Comment: Did you try setting the value property with state properties and reset them on onSubmit event?

Comment: Yes I tried, but originally I wrongly passed the properties (name, priority) from the parent component state (where they were defined) which didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value property of input with state properties, add their onChange handler and reset these state properties on form onSubmit.

This is not the complete code but you can do something like

```
import * as React from "react";

const taskAdd = (props: { handleAdd: any }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState("");
  const onSubmit = () => {
    setName("");
    setPriority("");
    props.handleAdd(//some-data);
  };
  return (
    <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
      <table className="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(value) => setName(value)}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="priority"
                placeholder="Priority"
                value={priority}
                onChange={(value) => setPriority(value)}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                Add
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  );
};

export default taskAdd;
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't work at first try (I was not able to call setName(value) and setPriority(value) directly from the onChange and also had to tweak some details) but the idea works well :-)

Answer (score 1):

you must set default value for your inputs like bellow:

```
class App extends Component {
   state={
     name: '',
     priority: '',
   }

   handleAdd = event => {
     ...
     ...
     this.setState({...state, name: '', priority: '')
   }

}
```

```
<td>
   <input type="text" className="form-control" value={props.name} name="name" placeholder="Name"></input>
</td>
<td>
   <input type="text" className="form-control" value={props.priority} name="priority" placeholder="Priority"></input>
</td>
```

or you can reset the input by JavaScript like bellow:

```
document.getElementsByName('name').value = '';
document.getElementsByName('priority').value = '';
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but without `onChange` event I wasn't able to change the input values.